# module to abstract limitations of GQL

Tags: python, google-app-engine, gql

I am after a Python module for Google App Engine that abstracts away limitations of the GQL.

Specifically I want to store big files (> 1MB) and retrieve all records for a model (> 1000). I have my own code that handles this at present but would prefer to build on existing work, if available.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of any libraries that do that. You may want to reconsider what you're doing, at least in terms of retrieving more than 1000 results - those operations are not available because they're expensive, and needing to evade them is usually (though not always) a sign that you need to rearchitect your app to do less work at read time.

Comment: Or perhaps outgrown appengine.